# How to upload files to Google Cloud Storage Bucket subdirectory

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload files to google cloud storage bucket subdirectories using Go. The only reference code I found is [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample).

```
wc := client.Bucket(bucket).Object(object).NewWriter(ctx)
```

The `object` here is a string of your file name but the file path is not allowed. It will throw the following error when I use a file name like `/path/filename`. It works only if you use `filename`.

> connect: can't assign requested address

Previously I use node.js and it works fine.

```
await bucket.upload(filePath, { destination: `path/filename`, resumable:false });
```

How can I achieve that with Go?

Comment: Omit the leading slash. `"path/filename"` should work just fine.

Comment: That really works! Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not upload files to Google Cloud Storage Bucket subdirectory because the notion of `Subdirectory` does not exist on GCS.

Google Cloud Storage objects are a flat namespace.

Therefore in GCS you have only buckets and objects.

Here you can find more details about how gsutil provides the illusion of a hierarchical file tree :

[How Subdirectories Work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with the Node example, the bucket is **always** the top-level bucket name.

Subdirectories become part of the "file".  GCP thinks of the subdirectory(ies) + the file as an object.  Yes, it is counter-intuitive.

```
const bucketName = 'top-level-bucket-name';
const subBucketName = 'sub_level/another_sub_level/';
// Cloud Function uses /tmp not ./tmp
const directory = './tmp'; 
const fileName = 'foo.txt';

storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(`${directory}/${fileName}`, { destination: subBucketName + fileName});
```

I ran into an issue with hyphens in subdirectories not working, which is why there are underscores instead.